# Installing MySQL gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I can't seem to install the MySQL gem. I'm using this command:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- 
--with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql/ 
--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.1.50-osx10.6-x86/bin/mysql_config
```

The errors that I am getting seem to indicate that I have no headers and etc. Not sure where I can get those. I'm on Snow Leopard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had massive problems with this as well on Snow Leopard, but this worked great for me: http://blog.m-schmidt.eu/2009/12/11/ruby-on-rails-mysql-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/. Good luck!

EDIT: you could also try using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), described as "the missing package manager for OSX". Some instructions on installing MySQL with Homebrew can be found here: http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2010/02/28/installing-mysql-on-snow-leopard-using-homebrew/

Comment: +1 for the Homebrew solution.  I've found it invaluable in keeping me sane.  I only wish Windows had something like it.

Answer (score 0):

His instructions in this link have worked for me time and time again. [master kain's awesome mysql](http://www.icoretech.org/2009/08/install-mysql-and-mysql-ruby-gem-on-snow-leopard-64-bit/)

Oh, and you did install xcode right?  From the disks before you did all this, cause that is where the headers are.

Comment: Yup XCode is installed. I'll try it out and let you know!

Comment: Didn't work for me. It's somehow not picking up on the headers.